# model bind error while using compiled template with ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to put ember's template under templates folder.
The related codes is here:

```
define(["ember","holder","emberData","text!/templates/index.html"],function(Ember,Holder,DS,indexTpl){
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
/*Route definition*/
App.Router.map(function() {
    // put your routes here
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return this.store.find("listItem");
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);
      Ember.run.next(function (){Holder.run();});
  }
});
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    defaultTemplate:Ember.Handlebars.compile(indexTpl)
});
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});

/*Model definition*/
App.ListItem = DS.Model.extend({
    col1 : DS.attr("string"),
    col2 : DS.attr("string"),
    col3 : DS.attr("string"),
    col4 : DS.attr("string")
});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
App.ListItem.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES:[...]
});
});
```

Related template:

```
    ...
    {{#each}}
    <tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td>{{col1}}</td>
    <td>{{col2}}</td>
    <td>{{col3}}</td>
    <td>{{col4}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    ...
```

Test results in chrome browser:

```
    Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed '(null)' (wrapped in (generated application controller))
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning your index template to your application view. Your template is now going to expect the application model to be an array when you haven't defined it. Assign your index template to your index view:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    defulatTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile(indexTpl)
});
```

Comment: Aha,when i saw your post, i knew the mistake i made. It works. Thanks very much!